# Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'res/values/values.xml'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.5

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':libraries:PDFViewCtrlTools:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
```

**In my caches folder I am getting multiple values.xml files, and these files are auto generating. I tried the solution of exclude 'res/values/values.xml' in packagingOptions in gradle file. I have also applied tools:node="merge" in manifest files so kindly give me a proper solution so I can build the apk**

Comment: have you tried invalidating cache?

Comment: Yes, I have tried invalidating cache and restarted android studio. I have manually deleted cache but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**After analyzing multiple solutions i solved this error by putting below line in gradle.properties file**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

**And only above line does not solve your issue then downgrade your gradle version to 3.4.2 version**